# Can you declare a DataTable as an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

```
DataTable[] dt = new DataTable[2];

for(i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
{
  dt[i].Columns.Add("id");
  dt[i].Columns.Add("name");
}
```

When I run this I get:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can DataTable arrays be declared and used like this?

Comment: Another way to create and initialize this array using Linq: `Enumerable.Range(1, 2).Select(i=>new DataTable()).ToArray();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataTable[] dt = new DataTable[2];

for(i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
{
  dt[i].Columns.Add("id");
  dt[i].Columns.Add("name");
}
```

I think in the code you are declaring an array with 2 positions (empty), but not actually filling them.

You need:

```
DataTable[] dt = new DataTable[2];

for(i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
{
  dt[i] = new DataTable();
  dt[i].Columns.Add("id");
  dt[i].Columns.Add("name");
}
```

And to answer your question, yes you should be able to have an array of `DataTable`.

Comment: You all are awesome. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this, you get that error because `dt[i]` is not a DataTable instance:

You could do:

```
dt[i] = new DataTable();
```

Full code:

```
DataTable[] dt = new DataTable[2];

for(i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
{
   dt[i] = new DataTable()
   dt[i].Columns.Add("id");
   dt[i].Columns.Add("name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your `DataTable[]` array elements first:

```
dt[0] = new DataTable();
dt[1] = new DataTable();
```

or within the loop

```
for(i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
{
  dt[i] = new DataTable();
  dt[i].Columns.Add("id");
  dt[i].Columns.Add("name");
}
```